# What is the output of "Build Xcode Project" in Mac OS X Automator?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, automator

I'm experimenting with the Mac OS X Automator to build my iOS app Xcode project.  There is an Automator action under "Developer > Build Xcode Project".

What is the output of this action?

I can save the output as a file, but I have no idea what extension it should be.  I'm not sure what I should do with the output either.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried piping it into the View Results action? Or, if you saved it to file, have you tried viewing the file? At a guess, it might be the build transcript.

Comment: You're right, it is the build transcript.  The Result Viewer just shows the path to the Xcode project.  I suppose the compiled binary is still inside there.  The Automator is not as intuitive as I thought.  Thanks for the tip.